# Tutorials on converting normal View to GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have experience in programming both opengl and using the android sdk but I've never used opengl in android and I have a project that is using just regular views and canvases to do all the drawing. That was fine until we started putting the app into real world use where there was possibly 40 or more bitmaps floating around on the screen at once and then the app SLOWS DOWN considerably even on newer test hardware.

I know that I can use opengl es, the ndk, or an `GLSurfaceView` but I would like to know from the community:

**Are there are any tutorials or materials geared towards converting an existing view to a `GLSurfaceView`?**

I'm thinking if I use opengl in a `GLSurfaceView` I'll get a nice performance boost.  The custom view that I want to rewrite is pretty straight forward but I had some trouble getting it to extend `GLSurfaceView` and properly creating the Renderer for it.  Everything came out black except when I made it all transparent and either way it you couldn't see anything.

So if some one can spare me the "Read the Documentation" answer and point me to a tutorial that would save me three days reading time I would gladly appreciate it :)

Comment: Too bad you stumped everybody, you asked just the question I was looking for an answer to!

Comment: just refer this link. its contain some sample code using GLSurfaceview.its useful to you..  http://hariandroid.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/how-to-draw-a-line-in-opengl-es2-0-in-android-using-touch-event-handling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this tutorial: [Android Lesson One: Getting Started](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/)